# mavenCentral() is not working instead jcenter()

Tags: android, deprecated, jcenter

mavenCentral() is not working instead jcenter(). When I use mavenCentral() I am getting below error message,

```
Could not HEAD 'https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout/com/google/android/flexbox/2.0.1/flexbox-2.0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

With jcenter() above error is not coming.

> Can I use jcenter() in my project even after jcenter() is deprecated. What is the last date of  jcenter() to be use in our project.

**Project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        //classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.24.4"
    }
}

allprojects {
    /*apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'*/

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**Module build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.kommunicate.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

          //Sensitive data
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        //jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //api project(':kommunicateui')
    implementation 'io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui:2.1.8'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` please?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I added app build.gradle. Please see.

Comment: could you remain the jcenter() ? There are still some apis that needs that. Keep both.

Comment: Also add your build.gradle of your project please, not of app

Comment: Use a vpn if your country is sanctioned by google (403 : Forbidden)

Comment: I use implementation("com.github.google:flexbox-layout:2.0.1") for flexbox after removal of jcenter in the project

Comment: @Per.J I used implementation("com.github.google:flexbox-layout:2.0.1") but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `flexbox` on Maven Central. There *is* a `flexbox` on [Google's Maven repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0), but only `3.0.0`. Some transitive dependency of yours is seeking 2.0.1. And, based on that dependency list, it must be `io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui:2.1.8` that is looking for the older `flexbox`.

Unfortunately, the developers of `io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui` have not updated their library, apparently.

You can try manually adding your own dependency on `com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0` and perhaps setting up an `exclude` rule on the `io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui:2.1.8` dependency to tell Gradle to ignore its transitive dependency on `flexbox`. Ideally, the developers of `io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui` would update their library to depend on `com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0`.

To exclude the failing dependency, change:

```
implementation 'io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui:2.1.8'
```

to:

```
implementation('io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui:2.1.8') {
  exclude group: "com.google.android", module: "flexbox"
}
```

Comment: I added implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0' but getting same error.

Comment: @AmitYadav: Then you probably also need to exclude the failing dependency -- I updated my answer to show the syntax for that.

Comment: I excluded implementation('io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui:2.1.8') {
  exclude group: "com.google.android", module: "flexbox"
} and its working

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the `FlexBox Layout library`

> https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout/com/google/android/flexbox/2.0.1/flexbox-2.0.1.pom

You get 403 forbidden for any reason. There's a `mavenCentral()` artifact using the `flexbox 3.0.0` in case you could use that one.

> https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=flexbox#com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0

You should add this dependency (or add exclude rule in your io.kommunicate.sdk:kommunicateui:2.1.8 or the one that is using flexbox)

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
    ....
}
```

For more info read this thread

> https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/issues/566#issuecomment-844630491

Comment: I added implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0' but getting same error.

Comment: Have you put the exclude in your library where you use flexbox? Also have you tried the close the project and clear cache and restart?

Comment: I didn't exclude. Can you plz tell me how to do that. I cleared the cache but it's not working